# Do I need a visa to visit Bulgaria?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, bulgaria, permits, moroccan-citizens

I am a Moroccan living in Italy for several years and I hold an Italian permanent resident permit, next month I would love to go to visit Bulgaria, and also Turkey and Greece, with multiple entrance/exit from Bulgaria. I know that for Greece I do not need visa and also for Turkey as a Moroccan citizen I do not need a visa, but about Bulgaria I have some doubts and looking on the internet is quite confusing, somebody says yes others no, please can you help to figure out if do I need to apply for visa or not.

Comment: There's a partial ruling for Romania and Bulgaria regarding national permits issued by the other EEA states.  You may be able to benefit from it.  Check 565/2014/EU

Answer (score 1):

You need a visa to visit Bulgaria. [This document from the Bulgarian Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.bg/uploads/files/Consular/050615_EN_VisaRegime_for_foreigners_ordinary_passports.pdf) contains an exhaustive list of all nationalities requiring a visa.

In this document, it's stated that citizens of Morocco do need a visa, there are no exceptions for residents, any exceptions apply to citizens of EU Countries only.

Comment: NOTE: This answer is outdated

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=ma&DE=bg&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=it&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a residence permit
>   issued by Italy for a maximum stay of 90 days.

So no, you do **not** need a visa